# Algorithm to match buy and sell orders

Tags: c#, algorithm, stock, quantitative-finance, orderbook

I am building an online stock game. All orders are at exactly market price. There is no real "bidding", only straight buy and sell. So this should be easier. Is there an algorithm that tackles the following problem:

Different orders with different volume. For example, the following buy orders are made...

order A for 50 shares

order B for 25 shares

order C for 10 shares

order D for 5 shares

order E for 5 shares

order F for 30 shares

There is a sell order G for 100 shares.

I need to find the right combination of the above buy orders in a way that gets as close to 100 shares as possible, without going over....

The Knapsack algorithm would work, but the performance will degrade very fast with a large number of users and orders being made. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT:

Here is my modified knapsack algorithm:

```
static int KnapSack(int capacity, int[] weight, int itemsCount)
{
    int[,] K = new int[itemsCount + 1, capacity + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= itemsCount; ++i)
    {
       for (int w = 0; w <= capacity; ++w)
       {
           if (i == 0 || w == 0)
              K[i, w] = 0;
           else if (weight[i - 1] <= w)
              K[i, w] = Math.Max(weight[i - 1] + K[i - 1, w - weight[i - 1]], K[i - 1, w]);
           else
              K[i, w] = K[i - 1, w];
        }
    }

    return K[itemsCount, capacity];
}
```

The only problem is that it is really bad on performance when the numbers are high.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    Given array prices, return max profit w/ 1 buy & 1 sell
    Ex. prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4] -> 5 (buy at $1, sell at $6)

    For each, get diff b/w that & min value before, store max

    Time: O(n)
    Space: O(1)
*/

class Solution {
public:
    int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices) {
        int minValue = prices[0];
        int maxDiff = 0;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < prices.size(); i++) {
            minValue = min(minValue, prices[i]);
            maxDiff = max(maxDiff, prices[i] - minValue);
        }
        
        return maxDiff;
    }
};
```

ref: https://github.com/neetcode-gh/leetcode/blob/main/cpp/neetcode_150/03_sliding_window/best_time_to_buy_and_sell_stock.cpp

Comment: For your example, which price is the buy price and which one is the sell? They are all lumped into one array? I need to be able specify one sell order and match with multiple buy orders, as in the example in my post...

Comment: Is that the greedy algorithm? The problem is I need to set a max capoff value.

Comment: Please check other answer

Answer (score 0):

I am still not very clear with the example you gave in the question description, for any knapsack problem we need 2 things capacity and profit. Here you just provided capacity.
Considering you just need to reach 100 as close as possible without worrying about the profit then it's much simple and can have multiple ways to do it.
One way is to just take all the bigger one which is smaller than the remaining capacity. If they are bigger than the remaining capacity then go to the next smaller one.
Time: O(NlogN) for sorting
Space: O(1)

```
function getMax(arr, maxCap) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  let index = 0;
  let cap = 0;
  while (cap !== maxCap && index < arr.length) {
    const remainingCap = maxCap - cap;
    if (remainingCap >= arr[index]) {
      cap += arr[index];
    }
    index++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't clarify earlier. I didn't use the straight knapsack algorithm. I modified it so that it only uses one array. Essentially, the weight and value are the same. There is only one array that is both the weight and value.

Comment: If the weight and profit are the same then still we don't need a knapsack solution. The above solution should work is just fine. As 1 Stock = 1 Profit then no matter which stock we pick up, at the end 100stock== 100 profit. And the best way to do it is to fill closest to 100, for that we will take all maximum first and if there is less space we will take a smaller value.